# Meaning of "would lead him to Esmeralda"

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning

> A few weeks later, Frollo’s studies were
>   disturbed by a loud knock on his chamber
>   door. “Enter!” he called out.
>   It was his brother Jehan. He had come, as
>   he often did, to borrow some money. Frollo
>   was not surprised. “Dear brother,” said Jehan.
>   “I am so sorry to bother you. But I need to
>   borrow a little money—for my studies.”
>   Claude Frollo knew his brother well. He
>   knew that Jehan liked to spend time in the
>   taverns, drinking with his friends. “Are you
>   sure you will buy books with it?”
>   “Yes, of course, dear brother! But if any is
>   left over, I may have a small glass or two with
>   my good friend Phoebus.”
>   “Who?”
>   “Oh, Captain Phoebus, a gentleman. We’re
>   planning to meet tonight at the tavern. But
>   only for a short time. After that, he’s meeting
>   with a young lady called Esmeralda.”
>
> The priest saw an opportunity. He would
>   give his brother the money to have a drink
>   with Phoebus. Then he would follow him.
>   Perhaps Captain Phoebus **would lead him to
>   Esmeralda**.

Dose it mean: by following the Captain he would see Esmeralda.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. "Perhaps **X** would **Y**" is a speculation that it is possible that **X** will **Y**. ***Would*** is used in this case because it is expressing future-in-the-past, but it can also be used for things that are future-of-now to express a greater hypothetical nature, as in:

> Perhaps sir **would** like some more wine.

Comment: Here:Dose" Lead him to Esmeralda" mean: by following Captain he could see Esmeralda?

Comment: He is stating that it is possible that, by following Phoebus, he might find Esmeralda.

Comment: Dose all the "would" in last paragraph expressing future in the past?

Comment: In this case, I think it's just for future-in-the-past. Sometimes it's hard to be sure if it's hypothetical or future-in-the-past, if the sentence is in past time.